# Could not set HTML element even though the element Class name exists

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to pull web data to Excel. however, I failed to set the object on table element by its classname or TagName. Can you please tell me where I am wrong and how can I get to that table and extract table data.

Thank you for reading my post and appreciate your help.

`Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim URL As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    URL = "https://banggia.vps.com.vn/chung-khoan/chung-quyen"
    
    XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLPage.send
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
Set HTMLTables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
    Debug.Print HTMLTables.Length '<--------- return result is 0
    
Set HTMLTables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("price-table")
    Debug.Print HTMLTables.Length '<--------- return result is 0

Set HTMLDiv = Nothing: Set HTMLTable = Nothing: Set XMLPage = Nothing: Set HTMLCell = Nothing: Set HTMLTables = Nothing</code>`

Inspecting the website show details in the link below

[The website element inspection is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH1Yj.png)

Comment: If you use "view source" instead of the Developer Tools and "Inspect element", you'll see that the page you're loading has almost no actual content: what you see in your browser is built dynamically after the page loads.  You won't get that using  XMLHTTP and a HTML document.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Do you know of any other way around to get to the table and extract table data? Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to use browser automation either with IE or Selenium/Chrome

Comment: A lot of the page info is coming via websockets. You would need to establish those and communicate with the server. Alternatively, look for an API. Or, use browser automation of course (much simpler!)